# How to run multiple commands in a PowerShell Alias

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to add an alias to PowerShell in my `$profile` file.

```
Set-Alias regrunt grunt;g aa;g cm 'regrunted';g ps;
```

When I run `regrunt`, only the first command is run. How can I make this alias run all of the commands?

PS: Please no comments about "do not commit minified files", we have all passed through this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can't unfortunately. Aliases in PowerShell can only be for a single command.

You will need to define a function to run multiple commands:

```
function regrunt {
    grunt;g aa;g cm 'regrunted';g ps;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Aliases in PowerShell are designed for a simple renaming of commands.  Only one command, no parameters.  To do what you want, write a function.

```
function regrunt {
  grunt
  g aa
  g cm 'regrunted'
  g ps
}
```