# Aliases command to connect GKE cluster from powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to connect GKE from PowerShell by using aliases. I read from article's that using New-Aliases PowerShell command we can set aliases, i tried adding few ways but couldn't succeed.

what i am trying to achieve is... On PowerShell when i enter `bot`, it should connect to GKE cluster. Command to connect cluster

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials genebo-gke --region us-east4 --project bot-poc
```

So when i enter "bot" it should proceed for the gcloud command.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please show the code you've attempted, and where it is you're having trouble with the code.

Comment: In Powershell Aliases are not made to call "multiple" or "complex" commands. Instead you should register a function as explain in [How to run multiple commands in a PowerShell Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37422666/608772) for example.

Comment: You can use a wrapper function or a scriptblock.